# How to sort List<Object> in Java 8

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a List of object where the Object type is just `java.lang.Object`.

```
List<Object> lst = new ArrayList();
```

lst has value:

```
[
["abc", "987", "er"],
["abcdefgh", "229", "df"],
["pqrs", "539", "ab"],
]
```

I want to list to be sorted on the Objects's second property value. The list should be,

```
[
["abcdefgh", "229", "df"],
["pqrs", "539", "ab"],
["abc", "987", "er"]
]
```

Comment: why not `List<String>`  instead of  `Object`?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense in Java. There's no concept of an "second property" of an object, and you won't get an output like that without some kind of JSON serialization. You probably want to create a comparator to sort on a particular *field*, and then call `Collections.sort()`, passing that comparator in.

Comment: Use String in place of object. then implement comparator on second property. convert it into integer and compare.

Comment: java.lang.Object overrides equals method and it has a native implementation of hashcode.

Comment: Michael and duffymo Sirs, since java.lang.Object has both equals and hashcode methods, can we sort this list ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom comparable, but this is a poor abstraction.

If you're using JSON, why hide the fact by creating a `List<Object>`?

I'd recommend using a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to manage your JSON and do your sorting on that.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume `List<Object>` == `List<List<Comarable>>`. So we can do it in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Comarable>> lst = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("abc", 987, "er"),
            Arrays.asList("abcdefgh", 229, "df"),
            Arrays.asList("pqrs", 539, "ab")));
    List<List<String>> sorted = lst.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(l -> l.get(1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Original: " + lst);
    System.out.println("Sorted: " + sorted);
}
```

Output:

> Original: [[abc, 987, er], [abcdefgh, 229, df], [pqrs, 539, ab]]
>
> Sorted: [[abcdefgh, 229, df], [pqrs, 539, ab], [abc, 987, er]]

Comment: What if first `List` is `Arrays.asList("abc", "1987", "er")`? Then your code will give wrong output.

Comment: Why do you think so? :) It will be  lexical sort. Is there any restrictions or rules for sorting in the question? Output matches, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. And by using a lexical sort `1987` will be smaller than `229`. Is that correct comparison for values that resemble numerical values?

Comment: I have just fixed the answer!  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `Comparator`. For instance, you can parse the 2nd element of each `List` to `Integer` and then compare on the basis of that:

```
// Some dummy data
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList("abc", "1987", "er"));
list.add(Arrays.asList("abcdefgh", "229", "df"));
list.add(Arrays.asList("pqrs", "539", "ab"));

// Sorting using custom Comparator
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> Integer.parseInt((String) ((List) x).get(1))));

// Printing
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[["abcdefgh", "229", "df"], ["pqrs", "539", "ab"], ["abc", "1987", "er"]]
```

---

But this method is not the best way. You should be having a DTO class for that and you should map this JSON to your DTO class. And then perform transformation on that data.